# Showing and Hiding jQuery ui tooltip manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tooltip

I'm trying to show tooltip of `<input>` on button click manually with jQuery ui tooltip.

For that if I set like this

```
<input type="text" id="has-tt" title=""></input>
```

for the first click alone its showing tooltip.But If I set title attribute with some content as below its working fine.

```
<input type="text" id="has-tt" title="Tooltip Text"></input>
```

Tried Sample is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7sbCL/).
Is there any way to do this without setting value to title attribute??

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$("#has-tt").tooltip({
    items: 'input',
    content: "Tooltip Text!"
}).tooltip("open");
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vCw9X/24/)**

Answer (score 0):

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7sbCL/2/)

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="has-tt" title="Tooltip Text"></input>
</form>
```

**Jquery**

```
 $(function () {
    var tooltips = $("#has-tt").tooltip();      
    $("<button>")
         .text("Close")
         .button()
         .click(function () {
             tooltips.tooltip("close");
         })
   .insertAfter("form");
    $("<br/>").insertAfter("button");
    $("<button>")
         .text("Show help")
         .button()
         .click(function () {
             tooltips.tooltip("open");
         })
   .insertAfter("form");       
});
```